Failed to update apt packages in ubuntu 20.04 at shim-signed
I am using VMs on GCP. and sometime I need to restore a the VM disk to an older snapshot. so the way I do it is I create a new disk from the old snapshot. delete the old one. and attach the new one instead. Everything used to run normally. I don't work on the machines normally its an automated pipeline that performs some installation. part of it is upgrading the apt packages. Now the automated build is getting stalled on this step:
Configuring shim-signed

-----------------------

The GRUB boot loader was previously installed to a disk that is no longer 
present, or whose unique identifier has changed for some reason. It is important
to make sure that the installed GRUB core image stays in sync with GRUB modules 
and grub.cfg. Please check again to make sure that GRUB is written to the 
appropriate boot devices.

  1. /dev/sdaxx (111 MB; /boot/efi) on 32212 MB PersistentDisk
  2. none of the above

(Enter the items you want to select, separated by spaces.)

I have read all about the disk UUID and everything about the partitions. I would like to think I know my way around these. tried blkid to see if changes after the snapshot. I even found out this command lately lshw -C Disk. It gets a GUID for the disk. but none of these change. even when I check the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg, the UUID is still the same. and the VM actually launches and everything.

This behavior is new. Yesterday was the first time I observe such an error. although multiple VMs were restored before and had no issue whatsoever.

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further. What should I do when someone answers my question?

This doesn't apply to what I need since I needed an automated solution but I'm keeping this question in case someone else needed such an answer :)

You can update the apt repository lists using the below command,
sudo apt-get update

Once this is done you can try this,
sudo apt-get install gparted

The above command should work fine. If it's not, you can download the file and do it manually also. You can install Gparted from the source. To do so, run the following commands in terminal:
sudo apt-get build-dep gparted
sudo apt-get install git gnome-common
git clone git://git.gnome.org/gparted
cd gparted
./autogen.sh
make 
sudo make install

If none of the above works, please check your /etc/apt/sources.list or try to change to the main server and then run again: sudo apt update. Also this could be possibly due to the /boot/efi partition lacked the esp flag, so grub couldn't determine where to put its EFI files.The solution is to open gparted, right-click Manage flags on the /boot/efi partition,click the esp tickbox,then Close.
Since the esp flag is set in gparted the question dialog allowed ticking the box for the new disk, press Enter and the package will be upgraded successfully. Refer to this.
Also before all this don't forget this two points :

Do not reboot your PC until you finish all the steps

Do not forget to update your grub before rebooting by executing : sudo update-grub2



my problem is that I wanted to do things in an automated way without any manual intervention. or else I would be able to simple select the partition manually. Anyways that is what I did. I'll keep the question because someone else might get this problem
